# What is the state of the rest of the world in The Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-2

In the *Hunger Games* franchise, what is the state of the rest of the world? What has become of the world in this futuristic society? Is there any mention either in the movies or books which would lead us to believe what's going on outside of Panem?

Comment: Your questions are basically dupes of each other. I'd expect any answer to one of them to answer the other.

Comment: @Richard - Whatever you believe, but they are two separate questions. One (this one) is asking about the state of the rest of the world (did they go up in smoke like the US did?). The second question is, How does the rest of the world view what is going on with Panem (how do others outside of Panem view what is going on inside of Panem). Overlap yes, but two separate questions. IMHO, you pulled the trigger too quick to close as a duplicate, but I'll play the game anyway.

Comment: The above statement is for @NapoleonWilson as well.

Comment: I really fail to see how *any possible* answer to that other question doesn't address this one as well. *"What's going on in the world outside of Panem?"* - *"What's going on in the world outside of Panem and how is it related to Panem?"*. Tomayto, tomahto. The other question pretty much entirely depends on the answers to this question and its answers are a superset of the answers to this question. Why ask such a dependent question instead of asking the question you really want to know right away?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Sorry, I was trying to abide by SE rules of not asking too much in one question. I guess I was wrong to follow the rules. I'll do better next time.

Comment: @Paulster2 *"I guess I was wrong to follow the rules."* - No need to get snappy, though. Following the rules is rarely wrong. If you genuinely think those are entirely different questions deserving to be kept open independently or that the (already asked by yourself, though) more general question doesn't abide SE rules that well, feel free to vote for reopening this questions and/or revise the other supposedly too broad question and/or gather more attention/viewpoints/confidence/support for the matter on [meta].